# Which functions don't work when using a noInterrupts() / interrupts() block?

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I have some code in an Arduino library that is time sensitive, and want to protect it between [noInterrupts()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/NoInterrupts) and [interrupts()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Interrupts). The documentation states:

> Some functions will not work while interrupts are disabled, and incoming communication may be ignored.

Is there a list of what (standard) functions won't work? In particular, I need save off the time with a call to millis(). Is the number behind millis() still getting updated, or should I move it out of the noInterrupts() / interrupts() block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear [from this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/is-millis-affected-by-long-isrs) that `millis()` in particular would be disabled by disabling interrupts, as that call relies on a on an interrupt attached to a timer that fires at **about** 1KHz.  I've pored over the official documentation though, and can find no exhaustive list of what can be affected.  I'm sure many are dismayed by this obvious lack in the official documentation.

Looking further, the timer (Timer/Counter 0 in the ATmega documentation) that controls `millis()` *still counts in the background* whether interrupts are enabled or not -- the question is, if your code spans the time when the interrupt **would have fired, you could miss a tick**.  See reference below.

Bottom line is if you need interrupts, keep your `noInterrupts()` sections brief.  And keep your code that is attached to interrupts briefer.  ;)  Whether you're coding in sketches or bare-metal, it's always important to keep interrupts fast in-and-out.

This [external reference is also interesting, shows the math and code behind the millis().](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/examination-of-the-arduino-millis-function/)